# fiddler to act as proxy for a remote IIS server

Tags: iis, iis-7, fiddler

I need to debug an issue on a remote computer on LAN. In past I have used fiddler to debug issues on IIS installed on local machine, wondering if Fiddler can be configured to act as a proxy to remote machine ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fiddler proxies all requests by default when you turn it on. It don't care if you are going to localhost or farhost.com.

Comment: Well I want fiddler (running on my machine) to act as proxy on a remote machine.  Meaning all request that goes to IIS on remote machine should go via fiddler running on a different machine

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler hosts a proxy to monitor requests, just set the proxy on the remote server to point to the proxy listening settings from Fiddler's about box.

Comment: will this be a setting within IIS on remote server?

Comment: I'd have to understand what you are trying to achieve better in order to tell you how it fits. Are you trying to capture the traffic to the remote server or capture requests sent by your application running in IIS?

Comment: I need to capture all request/response to/from IIS on a remote computer

Comment: Then each client to IIS would need to have your Fiddler proxy setup on their machines. Alternatively you can look into the logging abilities of IIS to achieve similar effect without having to configure the client machines.